# Magento 2.2.5 How to add additional products to cart from new checkout step?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, addtocart, checkout-page

I'm a newbie in the Magento! I created the new checkout step "Additional Products" with 2 buttons - "next/skip" and "add to cart". I want to add required products to the cart, but I don't know what I need to write in the addToCart method in my knockout.js file.

This is my template file /var/www/Magento/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/additional_products.html:

```
<li id="additional_products" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible" class="additional_products">

<div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Additional Products'" data-role="title"></div>

<div id="checkout-step-title"
     class="step-content"
     data-role="content">
    <br/>
    <form data-bind="submit: addToCart" novalidate="novalidate" class="form">
        <div class="additional_products" data-bind="foreach: getProductsList()">
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="product_id" data-bind="attr: {id: 'product_id_' +id, value: id}"/>
                <label class="product-detail"
                       data-bind="text: name + ' ' + price, attr: {for: 'product_id_' +id}"></label>
                <img style=" width:100px; height:100px" class="addit_product_img"
                     data-bind="attr: {src: '/pub/media/catalog/product' + thumbnail }">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class=" actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action add-to-cart primary">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Add to Cart'"></span>
                </button>
                <button data-role="opc-continue" type="button" class="button action continue primary"
                        data-bind="click: navigateToNextStep">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Skip & Next'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is my knockou.js file /var/www/Magento/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/additional_products.js

```
 define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/storage',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
    'mage/url',
    'jquery'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator,
    $t,
    storage,
    fullScreenLoader,
    url,
    $
) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/additional_products.html'
        },

        isVisible: ko.observable(true),

        /**
         *
         * @returns {*}
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // register the new step named "Additional Products"
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                'additional_products',
                null,
                $t('Additional Products'),
                this.isVisible,
                _.bind(this.navigate, this),
                1
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
         * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
         * for switching to your custom step
         */
        navigate: function () {

        },

        /**
         * @returns void
         */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        },

        /**
         * @returns void
         */
        addToCart: function (formElement) {
            console.log($(formElement).serializeArray());

        },

        /**
         * @returns array
         */
        getProductsList: function () {
            return window.checkoutConfig.additional_products;
        }
    });
}
```

);[image]

How I can add the required product to cart and redirect to the next step?

Thank @SwAt.Be for your message, but I have a problem with the router for this controller. 
I created the routes.xml file in the Vendor/Module/etc:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standart">
    <route id="additional-products" frontName="additional-products">
        <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

and controller in the Vendor/Module/Controller/DeleteItems.php with your example for testing ajax call and then I was planning change it.

and I call ajax to the next url

```
 var actionUrl = url.build('additional-products/Controller/DeleteItem');
```

Comment: the url build is wrong. Lets say the id in your routes.xml is additional-products and your controller class is located in Vendor/Module/Controller/DeleteItem then your url build is additional-products/DeleteItem (it already know its looking in the Controller path). Furthermore i suggest putting it in another directory so you have additional-products/NewMap/DeleteItem (just so you do not mix up with other modules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create an ajax call to a controller where you add a product using the checkout Add class.

I do the same thing but reversed to delete an item

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'jquery',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
        'mage/url',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
    ],
    function (ko,
              $,
              Component,
              _,
              stepNavigator,
              quote,
              customerdata,
              url,
              getTotalsAction) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Designit_HideProductByShipping/check-product',
            },

            //add here your logic to display step,
            isVisible: ko.observable(false),
            stepCode: 'check-product',
            stepTitle: 'Product Check',
            ProductItems: ko.observableArray(quote.getItems()),
            minicartSelector: '[data-block="minicart"]',
            /**
             *
             * @returns {*}
             */
            initialize: function () {
....
;
                    }
                });

                return this;
            },

            ajaxDeleteItem: function (item_id, parent) {
                var actionUrl = url.build('routeid/controllerpath/class');
                var item = this;
                $.ajax({
                    url: actionUrl,
                    data: {"item_id": item_id},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: 'post',
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $(parent.minicartSelector).trigger('contentLoading');
                        $(parent.minicartSelector).find('.loading-mask').show();
                    }
                }).done(function (res) {
                    $(parent.minicartSelector).trigger('contentUpdated');
                    $(parent.minicartSelector).find('.loading-mask').hide();
                    if (res.success) {
                        var sections = ['cart'];
                        customerdata.reload(sections, true);
                        parent.ProductItems.remove(item);
                        var deferred = $.Deferred();
                        getTotalsAction([], deferred);
                    }
                });
            },
    }
);
```

Note that this is an example js with code that has been deleted. It is ment to give you an impression

My Delete controller goes as follow

```
<?php

namespace Designit\HideProductByShipping\Controller\Checkout;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;


class DeleteItem extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerCart
     */
    protected $cart;
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;
    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    protected $jsonFactory;
    /**
     * @var Json
     */
    protected $jsonHelper;

    /**
     * DeleteItem constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $checkoutSession
     * @param Cart $cart
     * @param JsonFactory $jsonFactory
     * @param Json $jsonHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $checkoutSession,
        Cart $cart,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory,
        Json $jsonHelper
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Execute action based on request and return result
     *
     * Note: Request will be added as operation argument in future
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $item_id = $this->_request->getParam('item_id');
        try {
            $this->cart->removeItem($item_id)->save();
            $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('A problem has occured.'));
            return false;
        }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Item has been successfully removed'));

        return $resultJson->setJsonData($this->jsonHelper->serialize(['success' => true]));
    }
```

This also reloads the totals normally in your checkout.

Upvote and accept if it works for you thanks

Comment: Thank! I want to make sure your solution works and гpvote it, but I get an error related to the route. I updated the question, could you please help me?

Comment: answered you under your update

Comment: Thank you so much, it was very important for me and really helped.

I set controller file to `Vendor_Module_Controller_Additional_AddToCart.php`

and ajax call to `var actionUrl = url.build('additional/additional/addtocart');`

It work, thanks. Then I will look for how to add the necessary products to the cart of the current user. Good luck!

Comment: Glad i could help